# How to select the name which is not in commonlist?

Tags: python, pandas

Please check the error below... some values are present in commonlist so, I don't want value of df_head which contains commonlist… or can say `df_head = df_head - commonlist`

```
commonlist =df_head[df_head['Name'].isin(common)]
df_head not in commonlist
```

Error comes here

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ff85aff2f182> in <module>
----> 1 df_head not in commonlist

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __contains__(self, key)
   1520     def __contains__(self, key):
   1521         """True if the key is in the info axis"""
-> 1522         return key in self._info_axis
   1523 
   1524     @property

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in __contains__(self, key)
   2033     @Appender(_index_shared_docs['__contains__'] % _index_doc_kwargs)
   2034     def __contains__(self, key):
-> 2035         hash(key)
   2036         try:
   2037             return key in self._engine

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __hash__(self)
   1490     def __hash__(self):
   1491         raise TypeError('{0!r} objects are mutable, thus they cannot be'
-> 1492                         ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1493 
   1494     def __iter__(self):

TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do :

```
df_head[~df_head['Name'].isin(common)]
```

`~` will negate the values for which `df_head['Name'].isin(common)` .

*The `commonlist` is not actually required for this purpose until you want to store them for other reasons.*